# Como fazer uma tela de boas vindas em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quero criar uma página de boas vindas ao usuário que se logou no site.

A minha dificuldade está na criação da query como eu a faço e mostro o nome do usuário através de um echo?

**login.php** ***do formulário***

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pwrd = $_POST['pwrd'];
        //include database connection
        include('includes/db_connect.php');
        if(empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
            echo 'Nada informado';
        }else{
            //prevenção de sql injection
            $user = strip_tags($user);
            $user = $db->real_escape_string($user);
            $pwrd = strip_tags($pwrd);
            $pwrd = $db->real_escape_string($pwrd);
            $pwrd = md5($pwrd);
            $query = $db-> query("SELECT user_id, username FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pwrd'");

            //echo $query->num_rows; ver se tem algo no banco

            if($query->num_rows === 1){
                while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row->user_id;       
                }


                header('Location: admin/index.php');
                exit();
        }else{
            echo 'Nada informado';
        }
      }
    }

    ?>
```

**index.php** ***da página de boas vindas***

```
    <?php 

    include('../includes/db_connect.php');

    $query = $db-> query("SELECT user_id, username FROM user WHERE username='$user'");


    echo 'bem vindo: $ não sei o que colocar aqui';


    ?>
```

**banco de dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**--login.php--**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**--index.php-- isso é o que eu quero que aconteça, pegar o nome do usuário do login e mostrar em uma tela de boas vindas.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso sua página index deveria ser:

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 echo "bem vindo: ".$_SESSION['username'];
 ?>
```

Repara que no arquivo login, nesse trecho:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row->username;
```

Está sendo atribuído o resultado do `SELECT` a variável de sessão.

Outro detalhe, o `while` é desnecessário, uma vez que para atribuir o id do usuário à variável de sessão temos essa condicional:

```
if($query->num_rows === 1)//se o resultado da query === 1...execute
```

então esse trecho poderia ser:

```
if($query->num_rows === 1)
{    $row = $query->fetch_object();
     $_SESSION['username'] = $row->username;       
     header('Location: admin/index.php');
     exit();
}else
{    echo 'Nada informado';
}
```

Acho que é isso. Não me lembro se no index, vai precisar iniciar a sessão, mas o PHP avisa... Testa se der erro avisa, agente corrige.

Comment: nesse trecho  `$_SESSION['username'] = $row->username ;` quando eu coloco o username no lugar do user_id da Undefined variable

Comment: Veja, é `$_SESSION['user_id']`, por que está tentando `username`? Oh apesar que vi um erro aqui vou editar minha resposta...

Comment: Editei dá uma olhada, tava quase dormindo quando respondi essa questão..:)

Comment: sim eu cheguei a mudar pra isso mas continua dando Undefined variable que estranho o user_id mostra certinho porem o username não

Comment: Olha eu fiz um teste, aqui funcionou perfeitamente. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61362/xxxxx chega aqui

Answer (score 0):

Você executou isso:

```
$query = $db-> query("SELECT user_id, username FROM user WHERE username='$user'");

echo 'bem vindo: $ não sei o que colocar aqui';
```

Mas ficou faltando fazer o Fetch dos dados para um objeto: `$dado = $query->fetch_object();`

Depois você pode usar de duas maneiras.

`echo 'bem vindo: '.$dados->username;` (No seu SQL, você não está buscando o nome do usuário no Banco. Você tem uma coluna com nome lá? Se tiver altere o seu SQL, e coloque $dados->nome)

ou

```
echo "bem vindo: $dados->username";
```

Percebeu a diferença com aspas duplas?

Comment: como asim alterar meu SQL? Eu tenho uma coluna chamada username onde eu guardo os nomes dos usuários.

Comment: mas o username não seria o seu login? Exemplo o meu username é: macondesmacaneiro, mas meu nome é: Marcondes Maçaneiro.

Comment: eu quero mostrar justamento o nome de login.

Comment: ok, ali como eu mostrei no exemplo, você pode exibir qualquer coisa. Entendeu?

Comment: Sua resposta apresenta erros, considere revê-la, e evite ser negativado.